# Game theory question- information quality maximisation, opinions of the question

Tags: game-theory, economics, utility

I am developing a game theory question to help in deconstructing situations where information quality is comprimised and requires valuation against a set of criteria. I would be interested to know any opinions or suggestions for the following question, and very much to know any solutions that people arrive at.

There are five planes in the air circling an airport and three air traffic controllers in the tower. Messages can be sent and received to all planes.

All planes need to land safely but time is limited by a change in weather and it is now suspected that a terrorist group is in control of one of the planes, but it is unknown which plane. The captured plane will give false information.

The controllers have time to ask two questions each to any planes, this can be to the  same plane or to two different planes. Each ATC can only share one answer of the two they recieve with the other ATCs, which will thereafter be shared information. The other information is not shared with the group but can be acted upon by each of the controllers. The planes can be queried on the following information:

Location (altitude, distance from tower, bearing), fuel limit (in time units), no of passengers

The order of landing the planes must be decided by one of the air traffic taking charge based on the value of their information. The ATC with the highest valuation based on the following criteria will take control:

1. Accuracy: the extent to which the information is correct for the
   task
2. Completeness: the extent to which the information sufficient
   for the task
3. Reliability: the extent to which the information is
   correct for the task
4. Efficiency: the extent to which the data are
   able to meet timely requirements of the task